# static member variables initialization c++

Tags: c++, static

1. Why the compiler gives me an error when I don't initialize a value to a static member variable? Shouldn't it be initialized to 0?
2. Why I have to initialize member variable outside the class? (is this illegal because if you do so, and change the value of this static member variable inside the main function and you create an object of this clas, it will re-assign the static mamber variable to the old value) whereas const static member variable are legal to be initilized inside the class (and this is possible because you can't change the value of this static member variable anyway)?

Error: undefined reference to class_name::a

Comment: Can you post some code and the compiler error?

Comment: @hmjd : undefined reference to class_name::a

Comment: Note: that's the *linker* giving you the error, not the compiler. It's the same effect as declaring a (free) global variable as `extern` in a header but not actually defining it in a .cpp file. A global variable must have a consistent memory location known to all compilation units, otherwise they won't see each other's changes to its value. As such, it must have external linkage and be defined exactly once. It is *not* like a `static` (compilation unit local) variable.

Comment: @pmjordan : it's not the linker, the error is during the compiling time .

Comment: @hmjd : it's not the linker who gives me the error, it's the compiler

Comment: *undefined reference* is normally a linker error. If you're using an IDE, you might not realise that compiling has finished and it's progressed to linking.

Comment: i got the error LNK2001 and fatal error LNK1120 when same problem done on VC++ express. was never knew that I need to define the static class member variable inside *.cpp. Thought just the declaration inside *.h is good enough. Thank you for all the answer and explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error posted, the linker is stating that the variable has not been **defined**, not that it has not been explicitly **initialised**:

```
class A
{
    // declaration.
    static int x;
};

// definition (in this case without explicit initialisation).
int A::x;
```

The linker should not emit an error and the compiler should not emit a warning, as long as no attempt is made to use the `static` variable before it has been assigned an initial value.

Comment: ... you were doing fine and then.... In the last code sample, there is no definition. There is a *declaration* and the initialization value, but no definition. This can be fine in many cases as static integral constants have special rules, but you will still need to **define** the constant if you *(odr-)use* it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, just deleted that for now. I thought at declaration if a variable was assigned an initial value , `extern int x = 1;` for example, that this made it a definition?

Comment: Huh. `A::x` by default has value `0`, like any other class-static `int` variable.

Comment: @hmjd there is no such general rule like that. For `extern int x` if you directly initialize it, that makes it a definition. But for in-class initializations of `static`, it won't make it a definition.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I guess I'm misunderstood the difference between declare, define and initialize a variable. can you tell me the difference between them ?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, thanks for correction on class `static` definition. As for the initialisation, it was intended to illustrate lack of definition which is the cause of OP's error. Changed to "not explicitly initialised".

Answer (score 0):

A static member is not really stored in any of the objects created, because it is shared between all objects of that class.

It should only be created once, even if you create many objects of that class. Or even if you create *no* objects of the class. Therefore you have to do it separately.

Compilers warn about all kinds of uninitalized variables, not only the static ones. Having  a variable without a value is generally not very useful, so these warnings are good. Adding an `= 0` is not too hard, is it?